# The calculations in PHP and calculator are different

Tags: php

When I calculate in php

```
print (2224516644% (pow (2,16) + 1));
```

the result is -5748.

While in the calculator the result is 59790

Why ?
I need help

Comment: You are experiencing integer overflow http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php. Are you running on a 32-bit or 64-bit host?

Comment: Just ran that under PHP 7 and PHP 5.6 and it gives me the correct result : **59790** -- try it yourself: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa815664126bd6a1a49c7750f3c24b5a21ac7c29

Comment: You should use 64bit system to allow larger numbers. It seems You are running on 32bit.

See integer overflow:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow

Comment: Okey thankyou all :)

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren I've been using a 64-bit,,but still can not.

Comment: @EkaDaryantoPutra, thats because you have an integer overflow. The max int value is `2147483647` I believe

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren Okay, Thank you. Maybe any solution ?

Comment: You might try to generate the number you are looking for as a product of two other numbers which are not overflowing. But I'm not quite sure how PHP handles this

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php
Your value is higher than PHP_INT_MAX

Comment: It works fine for me : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa815664126bd6a1a49c7750f3c24b5a21ac7c29 , I think it has to do with his host